# how to make VSCode custom color ALL_CAPS variables in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I have the following code

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to customize a rule to only color CAPITALIZED variables like so:

[image]

Is it possible to somehow hack this in the settings? perhaps specify a list of variables we want highlighted with a #HEX color scheme.

Comment: This is an answer I wrote to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/55090334/9110128

Answer (score 1):

you could use [TODO Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight) extension.

in the settings you can set a `keywordsPattern` or even just a list of specific keywords (as the name suggests, it originally intended to highlight `TODO`, but the settings allow you to fully customize it...)

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

1.find out the textmate scopes by "Trigger the scope inspector from the Command Palette with the Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes"
2.in your users setting replace the "scope" in below code and change the color

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
     "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "constant.other.caps.python",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    }
    ]
},
```