# How to change color of Python classes VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024732/how-can-i-customize-python-syntax-highlighting-in-vs-code) and I'm getting stumped on how to change the color of classes in VSCode. Currently, it looks like this:

[image: from pathlib import Path]

... But I'm trying to change the color of classes and haven't been successful so far. So far, I've tried this:

```json
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3",
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.showStartPage": false,
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {},
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "entity.name.class",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF0000"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Not sure what the value of scope should be to get this to work.

Comment: when you customize colors name the appropriate Theme, Now you do it for all themes, light and dark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Inspect editor tokens and scopes` to get token name (look at the `semantic token type`)

[image]

Once you know token type set it in the settings

[image]