# Why does VS Code show the word "function" as a class?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My VS Code colors the word `function` distinctively and says it's a class:

[image]

But it behaves like a regular name such as `foo`. It's also not a built-in class, as calling it raises a `NameError` exception.

Does the `function` word has any special meaning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I customize python syntax highlighting in VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024732/how-can-i-customize-python-syntax-highlighting-in-vs-code)

Comment: @MaNKuR Not a dupe. My question isn't really about syntax highlighting in VS Code. It's purely about Python. The fact that VS Code highlights by default the word `function` was just a trigger for the question.

Comment: I believe... it's from Pylance. Do you have the [pylance extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) installed? If you ctrl+click / cmd+click on `function`, does it lead you to a class definition for `function`? Because on my VS Code, it leads to the pylance directory `/dist/typeshed-fallback/stdlib/builtins.pyi` file with a `function` class. It seems to being defaulting to some definition if it can't find one in your code, not sure.

Comment: And no, `function` is not a reserved word. You might be better rewording your question to "why does VS Code show `function` as a class", because I think your question is more specific to VS Code behavior, than of Python.

Comment: Thanks @GinoMempin, I get the same result as you here. And I guess you are right. I'm changing the title.

Answer (score 1):

Python offers a [`keyword` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html) that can list both hard and soft keywords present in a language - `function` is not among them.

```
import keyword
print(keyword.kwlist)
print(keyword.softkwlist)
print('function' in (keyword.kwlist + keyword.softkwlist)) # False
```

Comment: Right. Any special reasons for why VS Code does that?

Comment: @sourcream because `function` **is** a class. Try checking `type` of any function you define.

Comment: OK, but I'm not really interested in any function, but in `function`. `type(function)` raises `NameError`.

Comment: @sourcream Check duplicate I just linked.

Answer (score 0):

`function` is not a reserved word, please see below according to the python documentation, please refer below.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html?highlight=keywords

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/keyword.py

This module allows a Python program to determine if a string is a keyword or soft keyword.

keyword.iskeyword(s)
Return True if s is a Python keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of keywords:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=keywords#keywords

`function` is not one of them. You can e.g. use `function` as an identifier.

```
>>> function = 5
>>> function
5
```

E.g. `def` or `if` are keywords and you can not do so.

```
>>> if = 5
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if = 5
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> def = 6
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def = 6
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It is also not a built-in identifier as is e.g. `print` or `map`:

```
$ python
Python 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> function
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```