# How use prev syntax highlighting for vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I updated the vscode to `v1_43`.

It's too bad to highlight the new syntax.

How to use `v1_42` syntax highlighting in `v1_43`.

prev

[image]

new

[image]

Comment: If you want you can customize syntax colors as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55090334/9110128).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [semantic highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43#_typescript-semantic-highlighting). Semantic highlights are based on the type of the values, for example globals can be colored differently than local variables.

To disable it, just set:

```
editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled: false
```

Try leaving it on however. Semantic highlighting provides useful information and once you get used to it, the old highlighting will instead look wrong