# VS code theme color is changed automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: today]

Above is today's color theme. Please see variable name `SideMenu`.

[image: Few days ago]

And another one is a picture which is taken few days ago.

You can see `SideMenu` color is different. It's not a problem of `styled-components theme`. Because every static variable's name's colors are changed.

It's not first time. few weeks ago, I had this experience and it's very annoying. Why the color theme of vs code (This is default Dark+ Theme) is changed automatically? I feel very unfamiliar with this color, and I want to stop the changing and hope to go back previous color.

How can I do that and Why this happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How use prev syntax highlighting for vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621643/how-use-prev-syntax-highlighting-for-vscode)

Answer (score 2):

Ah! This is due to activation of [Semantic Highlighting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Semantic-Highlighting-Overview)

You can disable or enable it to to get the coloring you want. Usually its enabled for default themes. If you disable it, you will get your old colors back.

You can disable/enable it here

[image: semantic highlighting]

Or you can add `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false` to `settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

The is an option explorer.autoReveal in settings (either user or workspace) which controls if the explorer should automatically reveal files when opening them.

1. Open VS User Settings (Preferences > User Settings). This will open two side- 
   by-side documents.
2. Add a new "explorer.autoReveal": false setting to the User Settings document 
   on the right if it's not already there. This is so you aren't editing the 
   Default Setting directly, but instead adding to it.
3. Save the User Settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Please enter your `settings.json` file for clear question. There might a code snippet like `"workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "Default Dark+ Experimental"` or `"workbench.colorTheme": "so and so"` in the `settings.json`. You have to remove this, because this might set your default theme to some preset theme. So, you will not be able to change your Color Theme on a fresh start.