# Changing the color of django specific tag braces in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

Using the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089057/how-can-i-change-the-coloring-of-parentheses-and-brackets) existing answer, I have managed to almost get the effect I want.

Below is the image showing the template scope for "{% %}" in Django.

[image]

However, in the screenshot, you can see that the only tag that has changed color is the "{% url %}" tag, and not hte bright yellow "{% %}" tags.

How can I change these specific tags to match the url? I'm at a loss as I've changed the template scope setting for the given value, but it's only changing the URL tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to check that you don't have Bracket Pair Colorization enabled, as this will overwrite any custom colours you have defined!

Go to your settings, and search for "Bracket Pair Colorization" to make sure you have it disabled, as disabling this might solve your issue!

[Screenshot of the setting radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KQWg.png)